# Not supporting other then English language in JSP for login

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using Netbeans IDE to develop a JSP project for login. The login ID is in Hindi language which is appearing in my MySQL database which shows the Hindi font for user ID.

When I run this project in Netbeans, it works fine and I can login successfully, but when I try to login after deploying the WAR in Tomcat Manager, I am unable to login.

Do I need to add UTF-8 to web.xml file?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you aren't processing the POST request body with UTF-8. You can enforce that by adding the following line *before* the request body is ever been touched (i.e. *before* the first-time call of a `request.getParameter()` and so on):

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

To prevent repeating/copypasting this line over all your servlets, a common approach is to create a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which does exactly this job. Then you can just map it on an URL pattern of `/*` to apply it on all incoming requests.

I think that you've already done it properly, but you should also ensure that your JSP is emitting the response using UTF-8 as well by `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` or at least a  `<jsp-config>` entry in `web.xml` which would apply to *all* JSPs.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)